# Creating an Oracle table to remote server from DDL

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I am trying to create a table to a remote server based on the DDL create which I get from my local server. I can see that my code retrieves the DDL but when I execute it to the remote server, I get no errors but my table is not being created! Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? You can post suggestions in c# as well.

Here is my code:

```
  'Create DLL for STEP table
            Dim comGetDDLstep As New OracleCommand("SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', '" & sStep & "') FROM USER_TABLES WHERE rownum=1", conFrom)
            Dim readerDDLstep As OracleDataReader = comGetDDLstep.ExecuteReader()

            If readerDDLstep.HasRows Then
                While readerDDLstep.Read
                    sCreateDDLstep = readerDDLstep(0).ToString
                End While
            End If
            readerDDLstep.Close()

            'Create Table on Destination database
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sCreateDDLstep) Then
                If conTo.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    conTo.Open()
                End If
                'sCreateDDLstep = sCreateDDLstep.TrimStart("""")
                'sCreateDDLstep = sCreateDDLstep.TrimEnd("""")
                'sCreateDDLstep = sCreateDDLstep.Trim
                'sCreateDDLstep = sCreateDDLstep.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                'sCreateDDLstep = sCreateDDLstep.Replace(ControlChars.Quote, "'")

                Dim comCreateStep As New OracleCommand(sCreateDDLstep, conTo)
                Dim i As Integer
                i = comGetDDLstep.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
```

Comment: Could you put some debugging that prints out what your DDL is?

Comment: @mmmmmpie Thanks for your interest. I have found the solution to be: Dim cmd As OracleCommand = conTo.CreateCommand() instead of the above query command.

Comment: Excellent I assumed it was something else as your sql was sound.